# Is there a problem that had exponential time complexity but later was proven to be solvable in polynomial time?

Tags: complexity-theory

Pretty much the title. I watched a video talking about P vs NP and it mentioned that the event that sparked this entire debate was the fact that some exponential time problems were shown to be solvable in polynomial time. So here I am hunting for some examples so that I can dive deeper into how they were cleverly changed.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, checking if a number is a prime number was such a problem, its very easy to construct a nondeterministic algorithm for it, or an exponential algorithm (in the number of bits), but very complicated to find a polynomial algorithm (again, in the number of bits)

Comment: A few more answers are [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/48249/problems-that-started-out-with-hopelessly-intractable-algorithms-that-have-since).

Comment: Surely what you mean is *was thought to be exponential*.

Comment: we have never found an NP-complete algorithm that can be solved in polynomial time (otherwise P would equal NP) but many algorithms have had non-obvious polynomial time algorithms. In fact this has happened over and over again that we've found a problem thats in NP but can't be proven to be NP-hard only to later find a polynomial algorithm. The only major remaining NP-intermediate candidates are graph isomorphism and integer factorization.

Answer (score 2):

Dantzig's [simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) to solve linear programming problems is exponential in the (extremely unlikely) worst case, the above article cites several polynomial algorithms.

Comment: This is the example that I was given as well. In fact, I studied both economics and CS, and the story of how it can be confusing because the problem is exponential but it has polynomial time algorithms that work pretty much all the time was actually told to us both in my OR course and in my Theoretical CS course, by two professors from two departments from two different scientific fields. Must have left quite an impression.